# Laravel Eloquent - Insert to database by passing a JSON variable

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, eloquent

If I have a JSON variable with every key matching the table columns, is there a way to just to pass that and save it into the database?

For instance, if I have:

```
{
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "email" : "john.smith@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "111-111-1111"
}
```

And my table `User` only has those columns (I know, I know! I don't have a password defined). Can I just somehow use that variable to save a new entry or do I need to set each column one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it directly, but you could convert JSON to associative array:

```
 $userData = json_decode("{
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "email" : "john.smith@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "111-111-1111"
}", true);
```

Then you could use `User::create($userData);` to create new entries.

To do that you would also need to setup your model to allow mass assignment for these fields:

`protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone'];`

You can find more about this in the official Laravel documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent);

Comment: You are not converting JSON to associative array, you are manually inserting values in database

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. I just used the same JSON that was in the original question to better illustrate my point. There is no need to manually set all values.